# Joomla: How to refresh module changes without re-installing

Tags: joomla2.5

I am a new Joomla developer and I wanted to know how can I refresh changes as I develop components without having to re-install it each time. 
For example, I am creating a new administration menu, I can't see it until I uninstall and install the module I am creating? 
Is there a quicker and easier way to see these changes while developing?

Thanks

Comment: just goto your joomla installation and then modules folder(if your module works in frontend) and you will find your module named folder here, now open it and change files of this folder and your changes will be directly reflected on your joomla setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once your extension is installed, just use FTP to upload changes to the files. There is no need to uninstall and reinstall every time. You can also edit the files directly in the cPanel file manager if you like. Basically any method you want to edit the files is fine.